# Weird Typesetting on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Trying to create my CV on Overleaf right now. However, I am facing a very odd bug. As shown below, the text just collides with the sub headings (under experience in Google):

[image]

The code for this section is as below:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}

\runsubsection{Google}
\descript{| Software Engineering Intern }
\location{May 2013 – Aug 2013 | Mountain View, CA}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Worked on
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
```

Please do not hesitate to ask me if you would require any other details about the code, or the sections before or after this particular one.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable post? Most of your commands/environment are not standard LaTeX.

Comment: So, how is `tightemize` defined? My guess is you can just add something like `\bigskip` before it and it should move the content downward.

Comment: @Werner That worked out pretty well, so that's the answer I suppose. The behaviour of `tightemize` is not replicated in other sections though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can only assume that the `tightemize` environment produces a list with either reduced vertical spacing, or with a vertical adjustment to accommodate for too much spacing.

Moving the `tightemize` environment down should be as simple as adding

```
\bigskip
```

or some other `\vspace{<len>}` amount before the environment.